# answers and comments to my question disappeared?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, deleted-comments

I have this question and there was an answer to it and I got a notification by email that some news comments exist but when I check the page there are no answers or comments that were previously there.

[Retina 4 2x is never used for iPhone 5 simulator in Xcode 6.2 image asset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29374340/retina-4-2x-is-never-used-for-iphone-5-simulator-in-xcode-6-2-image-asset)

[image]

Comment: It was deleted by a mod.

Comment: The post was deleted; probably because it was not an answer to your question: *I tried this out any everything seemed to work both setting the image view's image in code or in IB.*, with 3 screenshots.

Comment: The post was drawing complaints from other users, it was a "no problem when I try it" answer with very little evidence.  Albeit upvoted as helpful.  Moderator response to such complaints is not always consistent, most let them steep for a while to give the poster a chance to improve his post.  This one likes a clean slate with a hair-trigger delete button.  Maybe the user will repost, it is fairly unlikely.  You got 2 more days of attention, edit your question to allow other users to repro your problem.  The screenshots don't really cut it.  Use a paste-bin or a github project.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the really helpful advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you ask a question and someone answers, it might happen that the answer is not related to your question or not a proper answer at all. In this case, a moderator can delete that answer. Deleted answers are only visible to moderators and users which have at least 10K (10,000) reputation on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why someone give me down vote?

Answer (score 1):

Your question has an answer that was deleted by a moderator. You need [10,000 reputation to view deleted posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

Answer (score 1):

[The answer was deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29374340/retina-4-2x-is-never-used-for-iphone-5-simulator-in-xcode-6-2-image-asset/29456156#29456156) in response to an "Not an answer" flag from a user; from the moderator console, it did not look like an answer (we don't see images/links when we're processing flags), it looked like a clarifying comment.